# Library is not importing

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, react-navigation, libraries

I am trying to import the react-navigation library in my react native project.
But it is giving me this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: IbexCrypto@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from @react-navigation/stack@5.14.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/stack@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0" from @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.10
npm ERR! node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view
npm ERR!   peer @react-native-community/masked-view@">= 0.1.0" from @react-navigation/stack@5.14.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-navigation/stack
npm ERR!     @react-navigation/stack@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-17T15_24_47_867Z-debug.log
```

It is also giving me the same error while I try to import some other libraries too.
Previously when I import the navigation library in my old project it works fine but now it is giving me this error.

Kindly, someone tells me why this error is showing. And how to resolve the issue and how to avoid the same problem in the future.

I will be very thankful if someone helps me as I am a relative beginner in development and do not know the logic of this error.

Comment: What have you tried already? Deleting the `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again? Deleting `npm` cache? Anything?

Comment: Nope, I didn't try anything

Comment: Well, that's the golden rule of SO that most of users aren't following: you should first try everything that comes to your mind, google every possible thing that could be related to your problem and then, and only then, if you didn't find a solution, write a question on SO with examples and everything you've tried so far.

Comment: By anything, I didn't mean that an error appears and I run to SO and post the question. Obviously, I try every possible solution to the problem that comes to my mind and on google but when it didn't work then I post the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a **dependency conflict**! It means that you have an **incorrect** and **potentially** broken dependency.
Try this first:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

This command removes the `node_modules` folder and then installs the dependencies you have in your `package.json`

If it doesn't work, try to run `npm install` with the command `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps`.

**In your case:**
`npm install @react-navigation/native --force`

or: `npm install @react-navigation/native --legacy-peer-deps`

**Description of the commands:**

`--force`: forces `npm install` to install the dependencies you want to install.

`-legacy-peer-deps`: --legacy-peer-deps: ignore all peerDependencies when installing.

These commands it's necessary in some cases but as standard `npm install` should be enough to install the dependencies from your `package.json` file.

Comment: Then why are some libraries are importing and some are not?

Comment: Some of the libraries you import are maybe not supported for your frameworks version which is described in the docs for every separate library.

Comment: Ok. Can you please describe the commands?

Answer (score 0):

use commond

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

for import  the react-navigation library

Answer (score 0):

For your issues, this two command may works

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

or

```
npm install --force
```

React navigation command in version 3 and 4

```
npm install —-save react-navigation
```

There are some minor changes in navigation 4
[React navigaiton](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started)

React navigation command in version 5

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

You can import like below code

```
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
```

Answer (score 0):

please refer official docs for react-navigation and install all the necessery dependency from here:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started

after installing dependency run

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

and then

```
react-native run-android
```